# ForbiddenAttributesError on build with nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, nested-attributes

**Edit 1 :** This is related to CanCan gem.

This is a nested_attributes issue. On single form the user can create an Account, a User account (as 'owner') and a Team --- all linked to the account.
The form works fine with the Owner-only nested attribute, but once I add the Team nested attributes I get an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError.
I've researched the build method for nested models, and I think my syntax is correct in my accounts controller -- note the difference between has_one and has_many.
I really hit a wall...
Thanks for any help.

My models are :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS = %w(www)
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :teams
  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :teams

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant :account
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :account
  validates_inclusion_of :active, :in => [true, false]
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_nil: false
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :name

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 
  acts_as_tenant :account
  belongs_to :team
  validates :lastname, presence: true, allow_nil: false
  validates :firstname, presence: true, allow_nil: false
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :email

  def self.current_id
    Thread.current_user[:user_id]
  end
```

My Accounts controller :

**Edit 2 :** if I comment out `load_and_authorize_resource`it works.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  #load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
    @account.teams.build
    #@account.teams.build(teams_params)  # tried this
    #@account.teams.build(params[:team])  # tried this
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    respond_to do |format|
     if @account.save
       format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain) }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
 Private
  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :name, :logo, :owner_id, :time_zone, :default_language, :publish_to_wall_new_employee, :publish_to_wall_new_document, :publish_to_wall_published_schedule, :publish_to_wall_modified_schedule, teams_attributes: [:id, :name, :account_id], owner_attributes: [:lastname, :firstname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_id])
    end
 end
```

In my Teams controller, I have :

```
private
  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :active, :account_id)
  end
```

In my Users controller, I have :

```
private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :account_id, :avatar, :role, :street_address, :zip, :city, :phone, :dob, :pob, :citizenship, :team_id, :contract_time)
   end
```

My form is quite long, so this is just an excerpt :

```
 <%= form_for @account, html: {id: 'accounts-new-form'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
      <%= o.label :firstname, "Your firstname" %>
      <%= o.text_field :firstname, options = {class: "form-control required", rel: "FirstName"} %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :subdomain, "Choose a subdomain" %>
    <%= f.text_field :subdomain, options = {class: "form-control required", rel: "Subdomain"} %>
    <%= f.fields_for :teams do |t| %>
      <%= t.label :name, "Choose a team name" %>
      <%= t.text_field :name, options = {class: "form-control required", rel: "Team"} %>
    <% end %>
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Below beginning of full error message :

```
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UTdyTCq3hpxR/w23JzJnWYozOLQhxpfOZPLql6b5+m8=", "account"=>{"owner_attributes"=>{"firstname"=>"john", "lastname"=>"Doe", "email"=>"john@test8.com",     "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "name"=>"Test8 Inc", "subdomain"=>"test8", "teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Test8-Team-A"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
  Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" IS NULL  ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = '' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:24:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:85:in `build_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
```

**Edit 3 :** this is my ability.rb :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
     user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
     can :create, Account

     # only owner can read & manage Account details
     can :manage, Account if user.role == "owner"
     cannot :read, Account if user.role == "employee"
     cannot :read, Account if user.role == "manager"

     # owner has full access to User details, manager can create/edit all User details, employee can read/list other User details
     # employee can edit own details except contract information
     can :manage, User if user.role == "owner"
     can :manage, User if user.role == "manager"
     cannot :update, User if user.role == "employee"
     can :update, User, :id => user.id  # a user can only update its own record
     can :avatar, User, :id => user.id  # a user can only edit own photo
     can :address, User, :id => user.id  # a user can only update its own address
     can :view_contract, User, :id => user.id # a user cannot updedit own contract infos
     can :read, User if user.role == "employee"
     can :home, User if user.role == "employee"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message in full? Thanks.

Comment: @EgeErsoz full error message added to body

Comment: Just try @account.teams.build

Comment: This is not a beauty contest. If you vote the question down please say why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fields_for for team:

```
<%= f.fields_for :teams do |t| %>
```

Apparently Rails is not generating **teams_attributes** for parameter, but just **team**. As you don't whitelist **team**, you get this error.

Comment: This is exactly what's in my code. Am I missing something ??

Comment: I's sorry. There was nothing there when I saw.

Comment: There. I changed the answer.

Comment: @user2721211 You should notice the plural `teams` which is not same in your code as it is singular `team`.That is causing the error.

Comment: @Pavan I tried **f.fields_for :teams** : same error

Comment: What does your parameters look like now after this change?

Comment: @Tiago `def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :name, :logo, :owner_id, :time_zone, :default_language, :publish_to_wall_new_employee, :publish_to_wall_new_document, :publish_to_wall_published_schedule, :publish_to_wall_modified_schedule, teams_attributes: [:id, :name, :active, :account_id], owner_attributes: [:lastname, :firstname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_id])
  end`

Comment: @Tiago now I'm getting teams_attributes out : `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+YnSeZ3jaodVEyIdddHj9S3Ga5dW2OrWqJ1Uxmcioxg=", "account"=>{"owner_attributes"=>{"firstname"=>"john8", "lastname"=>"SEV8", "email"=>"john@test8.com", "password"=>"xx", "password_confirmation"=>"xx"}, "name"=>"Test8 Inc", "subdomain"=>"test8", "teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Test8-Team-A"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Account", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"accounts"}` but still same error...

Comment: @TiagoFarias you were right about pluralized teams in the fields_for tag, now it generates the teams_attributes. However I still get the same error, so I cannot flag the question as resolved :(

Comment: `fields_for teams`fixed one aspect of the problem. But main issue was with `load_and_authorize_resource`declaration in AccountsController.

Answer (score 0):

Your account_params method in AccountController is missing quite a few of the params you're trying to pass through it.  At the very least, `:name`, `team: [:name]`, `:subdomain` and `commit`

Strong params is a pretty major source of confusion so let me try to explain what's actually happening, in the hope that it will help you solve your own problem, which isn't really about the ForbiddenAttributesError, but is about not understanding strong_params.

When you're creating an object based on user input, you can either restrict access at the model level or at the controller level.  In Rails 3, this was at the model level, with attr_accessible, but that had a [very notable failure](https://gist.github.com/peternixey/1978249) wherein somebody correctly guessed that they had left wide open the permissions to assign administrator privileges.  In Rails 4, this whole architecture was changed to force authorization at the controller level.  That change is what strong_params does.

Now, in every controller, you need to manually whitelist what's allowed through.  You do this with the `require` and `permit` methods that you're using in account_params.  You've probably noticed in tutorials and example code that every controller is doing something like `mymodel_params`.  Then, in your `#create` and `#update` methods, you invariably have a line like `MyModel.new(mymodel_params)` and `@mymodel.update_attributes(mymodel_params)`.

**This is the key to understanding strong_params**

What's happening here is:

1. In `mymodel_params`, you're writing down a list of parameters you want to whitelist.
2. strong_params takes in the raw params hash from the browser and whitelists everything you said was safe.  It spits back a copy of your params hash with just the whitelisted params.  It also marks them specially to say "hey guys, it's cool, these are allowed"
3. If you're passing anything not whitelisted in your params hash and try to update or create a new record with it, it will complain at you, throwing a ForbiddenAttributeError, *just like it did here*

So, with all that written down, the problem is that you're trying to build a record without telling Rails that it's all okay.  You can see that in the error message: it writes out a list of params you're passing, starting with `account` then a hash of `owner_attributes`, which then has `team` inside of that.  Compare that with your account_params and you can see a bunch of attributes are missing there and the structure is off.

**tl;dr** What Tiago said- your form is mis-structured.

Comment: Actually 'team' is not inside 'owner_attributes'. That is ok. Check it out. But there is no 'team' attribute, it should be 'teams_attributes', therefore the error.

Comment: OK all answers make sense, but I still don't see the cause of the error. Mainly why isn't Rails generating **teams_attributes** for parameter, but just **team**?

Comment: I looked at the form to see if there was a structure issue, but it seems ok : the team fields_for is not nested within the owner fields_for.

Comment: @ABMagil Actually my account_params contains `:name`, `:subdomain` and `teams_attributes: [:name, :account_id]`. That's why it is so confusing...

Comment: So I finally got Rails to generate the teams_attribute, by using the plural form of **team** in `fields_for :teams` (question updated). Note : it is generating an ID in **teams_attribute**, but none in **owner_attributes** --- is this a hint ?